# OpenCL Thread failure

Tags: multithreading, opencl

I'm currently working on an implementation of the parallel BVH construction by Karras (2012).

The algorithm creates every node in parallel and calculates its children. (this is the kernel). The kernel writes the node's children and in its child nodes the the parent reference.

My kernel code works with completely random scene up to the size of 41 triangles. If I go higher, in some cases a single (sometimes 2 or 3) nodes don't have any values written to them except for the parent value.

I already double check groupSizes, and made sure that the kernel only operates on the right amount of items.

Does anyone have an Idea what could go wrong here? Is there a possibility to see if a single thread dies/gets killed?

NB: If requested I will post some code, but it's generated code from an F# to OpenCL compiler.

Comment: You using  fake dynamic allocation?

Comment: What do you mean by fake dynamic allocation?
As far as I know I'm allocating all the structs in advance, so I assume the answer here would be no

Comment: What OpenCL error codes do you get back from the runtime?

Comment: I don't get any errors back.. I found that at some points the threads where out of sync and I had a read-write error.. Now the algorithm works with instances of 12k triangles, but when I go higher sometimes I get the same errors as before.. ie some Values are not written to a struct that is touched by 2 threads.. even tho I sync before read and writes